# install Magento 2 API Client

Tags: magento2, php, api, post-data, swagger

I want to install this dial but I do not understand or obtain **GIT_USER_ID** and **GIT_REPO_ID.git**

https://github.com/netz98/magento2-swagger-api-client-demo

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID": "*@dev"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually they give an idea of adding general repository. It should be like because In your case, `GIT_USER_ID: netz98` and `GIT_REPO_ID: magento2-swagger-api-client-demo`

Add the following to `composer.json`

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/netz98/magento2-swagger-api-client-demo.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "netz98/magento2-swagger-api-client-demo": "*@dev"
  }
}
```

After that run `composer install`

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  thank you, but I have an error in the installation
  
  Problem 1
    - The requested package netz98/magento2-swagger-api-client-demo could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: In your question, You wrote `I do not understand or obtain GIT_USER_ID and GIT_REPO_ID.git`. So I think you don't able to get what is  `GIT_USER_ID` and `GIT_REPO_ID.git`. I share the way that are usual to install any repository but there is problem if they have the different package name so it create issues in require part. For me you should try other repositories.

Comment: yes thank you, I continue my research